# How to Randomly pick a color from an array of colors in Java?

Tags: java, bluej

I'm learning Java and programming for the first time. I'm using the `BlueJ` environment.

I'm writing a program to draw polygons. I want to change color after every line has been drawn. To do this, I thought I would create an array of colors, then use a pseudo-random number generator to generate a value that would be used as the index to get a color from the array. I've included a snippet of code from the constructor method, as I've been told I need to create the array inside the constructor for this to work.

It should be noted that I've imported java.awt.Color, along with java.util.Random. I've also included

```
private Color[] colors;
```

as a field.

```
public PictureMaker()
{
    world = new TurtleWorld(500, 500, "Picture Maker");
    fred = new Turtle();
    //Allocate the size of the array
    colors = new Color[7];

    //Initialize the values of the array
    colors[0] = new Color(Color.red);
    colors[1] = new Color(Color.blue);
    colors[2] = new Color(Color.yellow);
    colors[3] = new Color(Color.green);
    colors[4] = new Color(Color.black);
    colors[5] = new Color(Color.pink);
    colors[6] = new Color(Color.orange);
}
```

Below is the code from the actual method that will be called to draw the polygon.

```
/**
 * This method takes sides (int) as input and draws a polygon with that number of sides.
 */
public void drawPolygon(int sides)
{
    world.dropIn(fred);
    fred.penDown();
    int angle = 360/sides;
    int linesDrawn = 0;


    while(linesDrawn < sides)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int minColor = 0;
        int maxColor = 10;
        int R = r.nextInt(maxColor-minColor) + minColor;
        fred.right(angle);
        fred.forward(60);
        linesDrawn += 1;

    }
}
```

I haven't included anything to get the color from the array yet, as I can't get the array to work.

I'm getting an error message `Incompatible types: java.awt.Color cannot be converted to int`.

I'm not sure why it doesn't work.

I hope this makes sense.

Please let me know if you need clarification, I'm new to using this site.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: Please note that you were creating snippets for *Javascript*, which is very different from Java.

Comment: One problem I see right off the bat is you are generating a number between 1-10 and your array is only 7 elements...

Comment: Where do you get the error?

Comment: @brso05 Thanks, I forgot to update that after changing the number of colors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Color` fields are already of type `Color` - you don't need to call the `Color` constructor. The compiler is complaining because there isn't a `Color` constructor which takes a `Color` parameter. I suggest you use the more conventionally-named capitalized ones, too - and initialize the array with an array initializer for simplicity:

```
colors = new Color[]
{
    Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN,
    Color.BLACK, Color.PINK, Color.ORANGE
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick. I am still allocating memory for the array on the line above this. Is this still necessary? or could I put a 7 between the square brackets in your answer to allocate memory?

Comment: @user2331411: You don't need the 7 at all - the code I've provided is *all* you need... it will allocate an array which is the right size for the elements within the braces.

Comment: Another quick question. Why does this have to be done inside the constructor method, rather than the drawPolygon() method?

Comment: @user2331411: Well why would you want to do it every time `drawPolygon` is called?

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. It will be done once when an object is created from the PictureMaker class, but every time, if it was inside the drawPolygon method?

Comment: @user2331411: Yes. In fact, ideally you'd declare it as `private static final Color[] COLORS = { Color.RED, ... };` - then there'll be just a single array however many instances you create.

Answer (score 1):

Your array should be like so:

```
Color[] colors = new Color[7];

    //Initialize the values of the array
    colors[0] = Color.red;
    colors[1] = Color.blue;
    colors[2] = Color.yellow;
    colors[3] = Color.green;
    colors[4] = Color.black;
    colors[5] = Color.pink;
    colors[6] = Color.orange;
```

There is no constructor for individual colors, so `new Color` is undefined.

As for picking randomly:

```
Color c = colors[randInt(0, colors.length-1)];
```

where randInt is this method:

```
public static int randInt(int min, int max) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

    return randomNum;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have `rand` be a global variable, and do `Color c = colors[rand.nextInt(colors.length)];`?

Comment: I don't think there is any increase in difficulty. Sure, it would be faster to do it like you said, but the method just allows for re-usability if the op needs a random number in a specific range elsewhere in the project.

Comment: So this is basically abstracting the random generator into it's own method, and then calling it to assign a value to variable c of type Color?

Comment: Yes while also giving you the option of negative numbers should the situation arise (never with arrays). You can do this just as `Color c = colors[rand.nextInt(colors.length)];` which will accomplish the same task.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure how to give you reputation, are you allowed to click on the tick thing twice?

Comment: You can only accept one answer. Just choose whatever answered your question. No one's feelings will be hurt.

Answer (score 0):

I think your array should be like this

```
//Initialize the values of the array
    colors[0] = Color.red;
    colors[1] = Color.blue;
```

And so on...